# Where are Nokia Music playlists stored in WP8?

Tags: playlists, windows-phone, music-management

I have a bit of a mystery to solve. I just bought a Nokia Lumia 820 and set it up. I installed Nokia Music and connected my Windows Live account and Gmail to the phone. When I launched Nokia Music it somehow had a list of the playlists (as in, m3u files) from my home music collection.

I'm stretching my brain trying to figure out how this happened. I have no playlists saved in any folders on skydrive, I have never connected this phone to any PC I own, and at this point I hadn't even put an SD Card into the phone. How the hell did it get a list of my playlists???

Just to be clear, there are no streaming services involved here. My collection is strictly a pile of MP3s and M3U files in a folder on a hard disk on 2 PCs I own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer on reddit. I have Windows 8, and have at some point used the music app which scanned my disk for playlists and saved them to the cloud via xbox music. The phone then synced them down.

It would be a great feature only the files didn't get synced so the playlists are fairly useless